# Android: Playing a sound from Kivy background service

Tags: android, python, audio, kivy

I am trying to create a simple alarm clock in Kivy for Android.

I've already got communication between the background app and the user interface (UI):  The background app is sending data to the UI at a specified hour.

But I can't generate a sound or vibration from the service. It all works from the UI, but not from the service.

I did try `sound.play()` from `kivy.core.audio`. I get this from logcat:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'Play'
```

The same if I use jnius to vibrate:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'getSystemService'
```

I did try vibrations with pyjnius [this way](http://python-for-android.readthedocs.org/en/latest/javaapi/) and my sound sound, which, like I said works on UI, like this:

```
from kivy.core.audio import SoundLoader
sound = SoundLoader.load('sound.wav')
```

and then:

```
sound.play()
```

**UPDATE:**

After Lafadas' update sound still does not play, but function continues after error and does not break instantly.

In a logcat I see something like this, if this is relevant:

```
Kivy service log:
    [INFO              ] Logger: Record log in /storage/emulated/0/org.alkoWatch/service/.kivy/logs/kivy_14-12-02_3.txt
[    INFO              ] Kivy v1.8.0
    [INFO              ] OSC: using <thread> for socket
    [INFO              ] Audio: Providers:  (audio_pygst, audio_sdl, audio_pygame ignored)
    [WARNING           ] Audio: Unable to find a loader for <sound.wav>
    [DEBUG             ] OSC: Start thread <0.0.0.0:3000>
    [INFO              ] OSC: listening for Tuio on 0.0.0.0:3000
```

Comment: Will you please provide code were `sound` variable is declare ?

Comment: Sure: 
from kivy.core.audio import SoundLoader
sound = SoundLoader.load('sound.wav')

and ten just:
sound.play()

Comment: Which version of `kivy` u are using ?

Comment: Kivy v1.8.0, with Python 2.7. I installed it with pip as far as I remember. I'd put log from logcat here, but it has got too many trash records from other apps and services in it

Answer (score 2):

Just figured out how to use notification volume instead of normal media which almost always is quiet.
Here's how I got good, loud notification sound out of python on android:

```
from jnius import autoclass
MediaPlayer = autoclass('android.media.MediaPlayer')
AudioManager = autoclass('android.media.AudioManager')
mPlayer = MediaPlayer()
mPlayer.setDataSource('/storage/sdcard0/Download/beep1.wav')
mPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION)
mPlayer.prepare()
mPlayer.start()
mPlayer.release()
```

Comment: this works thanks, but as stated in the docs you have to put a ```sleep(n)``` method just before ```mPlayer.release()``` (https://pyjnius.readthedocs.io/en/stable/android.html#playing-an-audio-file).  Otherwise it does not play.  If your file is in the Download folder java's ```Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).path``` or just from Plyer library ```plyer.storagepath.get_downloads_dir()```, which uses the same method, can point to that folders.  Also, when using ```sleep(n)``` it is a good idea to thread the function playing the sound.

Answer (score 1):

You have to check if `sound` is `None`.  If it is, the file didn't load.

From the documentation for [`load()`](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.core.audio.html#kivy.core.audio.Sound.load):

> Set to `True` if the sound should automatically loop when it finishes.
>
> loop is a `BooleanProperty` and defaults to `False`.

So please check its value:

```
from kivy.core.audio import SoundLoader

sound = SoundLoader.load('sound.wav')
if sound:
    print("Sound found at %s" % sound.source)
    print("Sound is %.3f seconds" % sound.length)
    sound.play()
```

Comment: Now the function does not break on sound, but it still does not play it. In a logcat I see something like in the answer update

Comment: So I suppose it did not load. I still do not know how to load it and play it

Answer (score 0):

A solution is to use this approach:

But it was not working "out of box". Problem is described here:
http://www.reddit.com/r/kivy/comments/2o2ws4/problem_with_running_a_service_on_android/
A solution was created and created by user kived on irc.

The problem is on 178 line of _android.pyx. A fragment of code has to be replaced to this one:

https://gist.github.com/kived/c833c97bbd044e68515e

Also I had to dissable the line: #br.context = service in /services/main.py and add:

RingtoneManager = autoclass('android.media.RingtoneManager')
[...]
notification_builder.setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM))

To enable sound